# How do i load my graph when i switch page?

Tags: c#, wpf

Im trying to load a graph that i make using a rand and saving the value's in a array.
But everytime i load in the page from another page the graph resets from start.
I first tried to draw the full graph from the array on loading the page but the line's in the graph would be placed wrong.
Then i thought the problem is the way i go to my plage by making a new one each time like:

```
MainFrame.NavigationService.Navigate( new InvestPage());
```

and then tried doing it like:

```
MainFrame.NavigationService.Navigate(new Uri("/InvestPage.xaml", UriKind.Relative));
```

But the graph would still disappear.
I create the graph using a rand and a timer, here is the function:

```
public void InvestTimer1_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (InvestArrayIndex1 == 129)
    { 
        Stock1canvas.Children.Clear();
        InvestArrayIndex1 = 1;
        LinemoveForward1 = 3;
    }

    InvestArrayIndex1++;
    Globals.RatesInvest1[InvestArrayIndex1] = Globals.RandomNr.Next(0, 99);

    Line Invest1Line = new Line();
    Invest1Line.X1 = LinemoveForward1; Invest1Line.Y1 = Globals.RatesInvest1[InvestArrayIndex1];
    Invest1Line.X2 = LinemoveForward1 -3; Invest1Line.Y2 = Globals.RatesInvest1[InvestArrayIndex1 -1];
    Invest1Line.Stroke = new SolidColorBrush(Color.FromArgb(100,83, 113, 219));
    Invest1Line.StrokeThickness = 1;
    Stock1canvas.Children.Add(Invest1Line);

    LinemoveForward1 = LinemoveForward1 + 3;
}
```

Comment: `new InvestPage` is obviously wrong. you should create the instance somewhere, and keep navigating the instance object. Just for testing purpose, you can try declare as `public static` or use **singleton**.

Comment: I made a new static uri like this:         public static Uri InvestPageUri = new Uri("/InvestPage.xaml", UriKind.Relative); and try to navigate to it like this             MainFrame.NavigationService.Navigate(InvestPageUri); ?

Comment: please declare static InvestPage instead. i'm not sure whether navigate new uri creates the object again or not.